# How to check product has parent id using product object ($product = $item->getProduct();) in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I just need to Get parent id from child product.
If anyone knows, could you provide suggestions on this.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

### By Object Manager :

```
$productId = 42; //Child product id
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
 if(isset($product[0])){
     echo $product[0]; // parent product id..
}
```

### By Construct :

```
protected $_catalogProductTypeConfigurable;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,       
    \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable $catalogProductTypeConfigurable,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_catalogProductTypeConfigurable = $catalogProductTypeConfigurable;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
public function getProductData($id){ 
    $parentByChild = $this->_catalogProductTypeConfigurable->getParentIdsByChild($id);
    if(isset($parentByChild[0])){
        $id = $parentByChild[0]; //Parent product id...
    }
    return $id;     
}
```

Comment: Hi, Can I get the parent id from the ($product = $item->getProduct() ) object, rather than checking with config object. 

Could you suggest?

Comment: to get id : $item->getProduct()->getId(). Try this code.

Comment: Hi Rohan, The code you gave provides the product id. I mean to ask, using that object shall we get the parent product id (configurable product id) if we load the associated simple product id.

Comment: If you render product object from configurable product class then you can get it. But, I would like to suggest you to use construct format answer for getting parent id.

Comment: You can accept and upvote answer :) So, It will useful for other developers. Happy to help !! Happy coding :)